# Why is an OS with only a ready and running state inefficient?

Tags: operating-system, system

I'm studying for an operating systems exam and I cant think of a sufficient reason as to why the system would need more than two states. Could someone explain the reason further to me?

This is the question as its asked:

[image: exam q]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would also want a 'waiting' state. When a process is waiting for some I/O input or input from another process, it would move to the waiting state and another process could run while it is waiting.

This might help you some: http://people.csail.mit.edu/rinard/osnotes/h6.html

Comment: What about the "terminated" and "new" states? What is the purpose of these?

Comment: Terminated signifies that the process is complete and should be removed from memory. A process in the new state is just awaiting to be put into the ready state so that it can be executed.

Comment: Without the "terminated" state one cannot create or destroy processes at runtime, all processes will then have to be present at system start and will always run until system shutdown.

Answer (score 1):

What if a process wants or needs to sleep/delay/wait for some time/event?

Waiting for I/O to finish is a common example, which can be as simple as waiting for the next key press by the user or waiting for some client to connect over the network.